# Dynamically retrieve data from Excel into Word using parameters that are in the word file

Tags: excel, ms-word

On one hand there is an excel file with a table. In the table there are village names and a bunch of attributes in the columns.

On the other hand there is one docx file for each village. Within this file there are tables that need to be dynamically updated based on what is written in the xlsx file. If I was within excel I could use simple INDEX MATCH formulas that use name of village and name of paragraph to retrieve the right information from the xlsx file. But I am in a docx file...

To go through naming each cell in xlsx and linking it would be too tedious (there are hundreds of fields). Is there any way I could escape VBA? Thank you for any ideas (including VBA if really necessary).

Comment: You can mail merger option to pull data from excel to word file.

Comment: Yep I thought about that, but I would have to go in each file, create all the fields and link them. I was dreaming of a solution where I basically just copy paste a "formula"

Comment: May be no option in this case. Only `VBA` custom macro can help you then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DATABASE field in the Word document to retrieve the data for each village from the Excel file - one DATABASE field per village. See:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-database-field-04398159-a2c9-463f-bb59-558a87badcbc

You will, of course, need to create the necessary query statement.

An example of such a DATABASE field's usage can be found at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21847-mail-merge-into-different-coloumns.html#post67097